# Minecraft PE freezes after generating world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to figure out a problem on my daughter's iPad. She is running the most current iOS and version of minecraft PE. She has two worlds created in her game.

One loads fine with no problems or glitches, the other, when you tap to play, says "generating world" and then completely freezes. It's a 10mb world, and her iPad has plenty of available space, so we've ruled that out as the problem. How can we fix this?

Comment: I've been having this issue too with my sons android device. Often it won't even load the game at all, just black screen. My ipad version I haven't played in a while.